# Web Audio API: How to play a stream of MP3 chunks

Tags: javascript, html, audio, streaming, web-audio-api

So I'm trying to use `Web Audio API` to decode & play MP3 file chunks streamed to the browser using Node.js & Socket.IO.

Is my only option, in this context, to create a new `AudioBufferSourceNode` for each audio data chunk received or is it possible to create a single `AudioBufferSourceNode` for all chunks and simply append the new audio data to the end of source node's `buffer` attribute?

Currently this is how I'm receiving my MP3 chunks, decoding them and scheduling them for playback. I have already verified that each chunk being received is a 'valid MP3 chunk' and is being successfully decoded by the Web Audio API.

```
audioContext = new AudioContext();
startTime = 0;

socket.on('chunk_received', function(chunk) {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(toArrayBuffer(data.audio), function(buffer) {
        var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);

        source.start(startTime);
        startTime += buffer.duration;
    });
});
```

Any advice or insight into how best to 'update' Web Audio API playback with new audio data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have some code I'm working on that's nearly identical to what you're doing. Please update this thread if you ever finish. I will as well.

Comment: Jonathan, can you post your server code please?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but I have problems with the mp3 chunks, you have an example of how make a correct stream of an mp3 audio with socket.io?

Comment: Why use Web Sockets?  You can use just regular HTTP and use a simple audio element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't reuse an AudioBufferSourceNode, and you cant `push` onto an AudioBuffer. Their lengths are immutable.

This article (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) has some good information about scheduling with the Web Audio API. But you're on the right track.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, `decodeAudioData()` requires complete files and cannot provide chunk-based decoding on incomplete files.  The next version of the Web Audio API should provide this feature: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/337

Meanwhile, I've began writing examples for decoding audio in chunks until the new API version is available.

https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-stream-audio

Answer (score 1):

I see at least 2 possible approaches.

1. Setting up a `scriptProcessorNode`, which will feed queue of received & decoded data to realtime flow of web-audio.
2. Exploiting the property of `audioBufferSource.loop` - updating audioBuffer’s content depending on the audio time.

Both approaches are implemented in https://github.com/audio-lab/web-audio-stream. You can technically use that to feed received data to web-audio.